# How to replace \Z from String in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string representing a regex `str = "[A-z]\Z";`
I want to replace \Z with $ as \Z is not supported in javascript regex.

Is there a way to do this? I tried a few string replace by creating a regex for \Z but they don't work as expected. It also works on any occurrence of Z. Is there a way to achieve this?
Here is my sample code which has issue

```
var expression = "[abczZ]\Z";
var regEx = new RegExp("\\Z", "g"); 
a=  expression.replace(regEx, "\\s");
alert(a);
```

Comment: 1. Why don't you just change the expression...? 2. What do you mean "doesn't work as expected?" That's not helpful in any way. What happens?

Comment: I have a  use case where i get these regex from user so i dont have control over regex. Only this is that i want to support \Z in these regex so I need to replace Z with $

Comment: `"[A-z]\Z".replace(/\Z/, '$')`?

Comment: `[A-z]` does not do what you think it does. It matches `^`, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need one additional layer of escaping:

```
var regEx = new RegExp("\\\\Z", "g");
```

because you give the regex as a string, so one escape layer will be “eaten” by the string, retaining only `\Z` for the regex, which matches a literal `Z`.

You can also use a regex literal, in which case you don't need to double-escape:

```
var regEx = /\\Z/g;
```

Of course, to test it on your string you first need to fix your string. As it stands it does not contain any backslash at all. `var expression = "[abczZ]\Z"` results in `expression` containing the string `"[abczZ]Z"` because you did not escape the backslash. Exact same problem as described in the first two paragraphs.

Try it yourself in the JS console:

```
> "[abczZ]\Z"
"[abczZ]Z"
> "[abczZ]\\Z"
"[abczZ]\Z"
> "[abczZ]\Z".replace(new RegExp("\\\\Z", "g"), "$")
"[abczZ]Z"
> "[abczZ]\\Z".replace(new RegExp("\\\\Z", "g"), "$")
"[abczZ]$"
```

Comment: +1 for regex literal. only ever use the RegExp constructor if you're building the regex dynamically, otherwise save yourself the hassle of string escaping.

Comment: Tried you solution. It only replaces "\" before \Z result string contains [abczZ]Z. so its not useful to me.

Comment: You may want to escape the `\` in your string as well, because otherwise there is no `\` in there at all ...

Comment: also literal is not an option as regex string will come from user input, so no control over it

Comment: my bad..i should have realized that.. thanks for pointing it out